# Possible to read logged-on user's account name?

Tags: microsoft-metro

I'm developing my first Metro app using XAML. The app is for our company intranet use only. I have these questions -

1. Is it possible to retrieve the account name (domain\username) of the current logged in user? Do I need to use a WinRT component for this? I looked up `Windows.Security.Authentication` namespace and only `Web` and `OnlineId` are available.
2. I'm using the WebView control to navigate to a secure URL. If I open this URL in a browser, I do not get any prompts (since my machine is joined to the domain), but if I open the URL in a WebView, I get the username & password prompt. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Update - I was able to solve #2 question by enabling Enterprise Authentication in the Capabilities tab of the  `Package.appxmanifest file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For No. 1:

Please use **[Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.aspx)** class to get all relevant information

```
GetDisplayNameAsync()
GetDomainNameAsync()
GetPrincipleNameAsync()
```

e.g. to get the display name

```
 if (UserInformation.NameAccessAllowed)
 {
      string player = await UserInformation.GetDisplayNameAsync();
 }
```